# Move Entity object to MongoDB

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, mongodb

In our application we are using Entity Framework 6 and MSSQL. Since the database hit its limits, we are planning to move old data from MSSQL to MongoDB. Since we used code-first approach, our models are connected via virtual attributes.

Is there a simple way to directly save the objects to MongoDb and preserving the relationships? We could save the ids alongside the entity objects (that's how they are saved in MSSQL) but for that I imagine I'd have to write another class that has an explicit attribute representing the referenced entity id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to directly save the objects to MongoDb and
>   preserving the relationships?

Mongo is a NoSQL, document-oriented storage. A *document* is like an *object*.

You just need to get a persisted object from Entity Framework and store it to a Mongo collection.

BTW, being more strict, I wouldn't recommend this approach, because you may end up persisting Entity Framework object proxies.

To solve this, before persisting an object to Mongo, I would unproxy it using a tool like *AutoMapper* to map the proxy to a new POCO/unproxied instance.